# Why do I get incompatible pointer type?

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to use `GetVersionEx()` from the Windows API with the `OSVERSIONINFOEX` structure, but this keeps throwing a warning about an incompatible pointer type:

```
OSVERSIONINFOEX osInfo;
osInfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX);
GetVersionEx(&osInfo);
printf("%ld\n", osInfo.dwBuildNumber);
```

full warning:

```
id.c:31:18: warning: passing argument 1 of 'GetVersionExA' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   31 |     GetVersionEx(&osInfo);
      |                  ^~~~~~~~
      |                  |
      |                  OSVERSIONINFOEX * {aka OSVERSIONINFOEXA *}
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/winbase.h:36,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/windows.h:70,
                 from id.c:1:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/sysinfoapi.h:64:61: note: expected 'LPOSVERSIONINFOA' {aka 'struct _OSVERSIONINFOA *'} but argument is of type 'OSVERSIONINFOEX *' {aka 'OSVERSIONINFOEXA *'}
   64 |   WINBASEAPI WINBOOL WINAPI GetVersionExA (LPOSVERSIONINFOA lpVersionInformation);
      |                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: You must cast to an `OSVERSIONINFO*`. Internally, the GetVersionEx API will determine the type using dwOSVersionInfoSize. This is a common pattern with many Windows APIs.

Comment: @SimonMourier could you elaborate how to do so because

Comment: Just do `GetVersionEx((OSVERSIONINFO*)&osInfo);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetVersionEx()` expects an `OSVERSIONINFO*` pointer, not an `OSVERSIONINFOEX*` pointer.  However, the `OSVERSIONINFO*` pointer can point at an `OSVERSIONINFOEX` instance, so you just need to use a typecast, eg:

```
GetVersionEx((LPOSVERSIONINFO)&osInfo);
```